# Security Issues of App

Tags: java, asp.net, python, security

I am making an App ecosystem, which includes a Desktop, Mobile and Web all negotiating with same database using webservices. These apps need to be highly secure as they will be used to control Home security. For eg: Remotely Opening/Locking front door of home, remotely opening/closing a money vault kept inside home.

I want these apps to be as secure as possible, yet as least intrusive to authorized users as possible. Some security features I plan to include are:

**Web App**

1. 2 step verification, using a one time password sent to registered mobile.
2. SMS updates to registered mobile about any activity.
3. Deploying RSA secure token like [SecurID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SecurID)

**Desktop App**

1. Binding a user to a particular (or a set of) hardware id/s. Only machines mapped to a specific user are allowed to access.

**Mobile App**

1. 2 step verification.
2. Binding a user to NFC Hardware ID in Android Mobile app. (Similarly for other platforms)

**Database Security**

1. No direct exposure of database schema/data.
2. All API requests served via oauth token.

**Technology Stack**

Its not frozen as of now, but I plan to use either:

- Webservices Framework- Mule/Java
- Database- Postgres
- Web Framework- Django/Python
- Mobile- Android, Apple, Windows Phone sdks

or Microsoft tools altogether- C#, ASP.NET, SQL Server 2008 R2

I have following **specific questions** in this scenario.

**UPDATE:** on [Will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will)'s advice I am limiting my question to just one aspect.

1. Are there any *vulnerabilities involved* in the above security features?
2. Any other *security feature* which can be implemented that is secure yet not intrusive to users?

Comment: This is not a question, this is a project....

Comment: @Aristos I just need some healthy feedbacks on these questions. I have done my research, wanted to get community's take on this. Its fine if not all questions are answered.

Comment: I am sure for your pure intentions, I just do not know where to start... :)

Comment: @Aristos Well you can start with line of least resistance... Technology Stack may be?

Comment: This kind of question is discursive, and will probably be closed. But, fwiw, use the stack you're most comfortable with; it is better to have a working prototype that needs improvement than a well-planned product involving technology you don't know.

Comment: Additionally, I'd stick to one framework for your web app and your web services - unless there is a compelling reason to use two. Keep the frameworks you use popular and standardised. Reason for both of these - if you need to hire developers, additional or rarer technology requirements = more cost.

Comment: @halfer I am comfortable in django/python as web framework as its neat and manageable. From my experience Java/Mule is faster for serving webservices requests. Both are substantially popular. Moreover, the choice is dependent on the ease of implementation of these security features.

Comment: Sounds like you might be optimising too early. When creating a prototype system, always remember it might fail (possibly due to less user interest than originally thought, development costs more expensive etc). In general, development speed is more important atm than performance.

Comment: @halfer Agreed. Infact I am more concerned to freeze the security features now. Definitely, development speed is more important, scaling can be done later.

Comment: Sorry, we don't do wikis anymore.  Also, I'd hate to have users spend time composing an answer to this question (well, most likely *an answer to a small fraction of this question*) and get no reputation for it.  Your question is way too broad and cannot be reasonably answered.  I won't close outright, but you can expect that to happen soon.  Please [edit] your quesiton(s) and narrow it down to a *single question* that can reasonably be answered here.

Comment: @Will I have reduced the scope of my question to just one aspect. Thanks for not closing...

Comment: You are effectively asking for a security analysis of your project... With so many components involved (devices, apps, stacks), the answer to your first question is almost 100% certain: yes. As for the NFC hardware ID in Android: a standard app cannot access that hardware. The API is hidden and not accessible for normal apps and it does not provide a method to obtain the ID anyway.